# How do you bleed brakes on a 2001 Pontiac Grand Am?

Tags: brakes, pontiac, grand-am, bleeding

I've been trying to figure out how to bleed my brakes on a 2001 Pontiac Grand Am. I know how to bleed brakes, but every car is different, and I've never bled brakes on a 2001 Pontiac Grand Am. When I go driving around (in a church parking lot, luckily not out on the road) I've bled them twice, and there's still a lot of air in the hoses. I haven't done brakes in years. So I'm just curious. Is the brake suppose to go to the floor while bleeding the brakes? Or is it supposed to tighten up?

EDIT:

The passenger side was grinding and so when i changed them only one of pads was worn all way down on passenger side i changed them all and i didnt no i didn't have to bleed them so i proceeded to bleed and ever since the pedal goes to floor

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What work was done which made you need to bleed the brakes in the first place?